# Updating GROUP BY queries for SQL mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: sql, mysql

My hoster switches from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0.33 soon so **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** is enabled by default then.

I can't add **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** already to the SQL mode for testing purposes right now because of missing rights. So it's also not possible to just turn it off later when the hoster has updated the MySQL version.

So the only thing i can do now is to adjust the queries for working with **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** later and they should work also right now if done correctly.

I'm an lazy coder doing stuff like this all the time:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
table
WHERE
...
GROUP BY xyz
ORDER BY abc
```

Is it right, that i can't use the ***** (=all columns) anymore if using GROUP BY in an SELECT query? :-(

**Example 1:**

```sql
SELECT headhunter, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM table
GROUP BY headhunter
```

Do i need to add **amount** here also to the GROUP BY?

**Example 2:**

```sql
SELECT *, departure, DATE_FORMAT(departure,'%d.%m.%y') AS departure2
FROM table
WHERE carnumber1=''
GROUP BY shipid
ORDER BY departure DESC
```

What happens here? I can't use the ***** anymore here?

I need to remove the ***** and add **shipid** to the SELECT, also **departure** (**departure2** too?) to GROUP BY and **shipid** to ORDER BY?

Also i have to look inside my PHP code which columns i process after this query in the while loop and add **them all** to the SELECT, GROUP BY and ORDER?!?

**Example 3:**

```sql
SELECT customer
FROM table
WHERE carnumber1!=''
GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY customer ASC
```

Here is no adjustment needed, or?

**Example 4:**

```sql
SELECT customer
FROM table
WHERE carnumber1!=''
AND preparation>date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY customer ASC
```

Also no adjustment?

**Example 5:**

```sql
SELECT customer
FROM table
GROUP BY customer
HAVING MAX(preparation)<=date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
ORDER BY customer ASC
```

Is column **preparation** needed here (because of HAVING) in the SELECT, GROUP and ORDER?

**Example 6:**

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(delivery,'%M %Y'), COUNT(*) AS amount, SUM(purchase_price) AS summed
FROM table
GROUP BY MONTH(delivery), YEAR(delivery)
```

Just adding **delivery** to the SELECT and **purchase_price** to GROUP BY?

Thanks for all your hints, query fixings, explanations!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I modify your queries for each example:

**Example 1:**

```
SELECT headhunter, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM table
GROUP BY headhunter, amount;
```

**Example 2:**

```
SELECT shipid, departure, DATE_FORMAT(departure,'%d.%m.%y') AS departure2
FROM table
WHERE carnumber1=''
GROUP BY shipid, departure, departure2
ORDER BY shipid, departure DESC;
```

**Example 3:**

```
No adjustment needed as it's already compliant.
```

**Example 4:**

```
No adjustment needed; it's already compliant.
```

**Example 5:**

```
SELECT customer, MAX(preparation) AS max_preparation
FROM table
GROUP BY customer
HAVING max_preparation <= date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
ORDER BY customer ASC;
```

**Example 6:**

```
SELECT YEAR(delivery), MONTH(delivery), COUNT(*) AS amount, SUM(purchase_price) AS summed
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(delivery), MONTH(delivery);
```

All the columns in the SELECT clause need to do is be either a part of the GROUP BY clause or use aggregate functions (like COUNT, SUM, or MAX). You can utilize aliases declared in the SELECT clause or use columns that are in the SELECT clause in the ORDER BY clause. These guidelines must be followed in order to make your queries compatible with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode.

Comment: In the first example why is `amount` needed in the group by clause ?

Comment: Yep this gives me the following error:
Error: 1056 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_WRONG_GROUP_FIELD)

Message: Can't group on '%s'     So there is no changed needed?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm an lazy coder doing stuff like this all the time:
>
> SELECT * FROM table WHERE

Please, do not do that. In most cases it is wrong.

See [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful) for further details.

From [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

If the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) SQL mode is enabled , MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregate columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them.

In simple words the columns on the select list which are not part of an aggregate functions such as `MIN(),MAX() etc` should be part of the group by  clause.

*An important thing to keep in mind*. MySQL support Functional Dependencies, meaning if you use the primary key on the group by clause there is no need to add other columns because the primary key determines every attribute in the table.

Consider a simple  example which can be found on [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kt5jbvNr) as well.
In the following example only the third query will fail because col2 is not part of the aggregate function nor part of the group by clause and the column used in the group by is not a primary key

```
create table test (
  id int primary key,
  col1 int  ,
  col2 text );

insert into test values  (1,3,'Test1'),(2,2,'Test2'),(3,1,'Test3'),(4,1,'Test4');
```

Query 1

```
SELECT id,sum(col1),col2
FROM test
GROUP BY id;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT sum(col1),col2
FROM test
GROUP BY id;
```

Query 3

```
SELECT sum(col1),col2
FROM test
GROUP BY col1;
```

Comment: Regarding to "SELECT ALL": I have also a table with 40 (!) columns. Do i really need to add all those 40 colums to the SELECT now,  perhaps also to GROUP BY and ORDER BY?!? (when i need all columns further in the code of course)

Comment: @WeekendCoder yes , add all the needed columns in the select part, as per the group by clause if you use the primary key column on the group by there is no need to add other columns otherwise you need to add every column which is in the select clause and not part of an aggregate function. I know that is 'annoyed' , but thats the best practice to work